# listbox loads so slow using knockout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a group of radio buttons a dropdownlist and a list box. When the use changes dropdownlist listbox gets filled up based on radio buttons.(I have other parameters too). It takes 2 mins for 6.000 records to load listbox. Is there any other faster way? Would it be faster if I fill up listbox in controller using dropdown change event?if yes how can I do that?

```
   $.getJSON('GetRecipients', { state: state, distrChan: valueOfDistrChan, isactive: valueOfrdoActTer, groups: groups, mktGroup: valueOfMarkGrp, subjectID: subjectID }, function (data) {
        var result = $.parseJSON(data);
        $.each(result, function (i, item) {
            self.recipientList.push(item);
        });

    });
```

view:

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedRecipients, new MultiSelectList(new[] { "" }), new { @class = "form-control", @size = 11, data_bind = "options: recipientList,optionsValue:function(i) {return i.ID}, optionsText: function(i) {return i.LastName +', '+ i.FirstName}" })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `result` is an array, try assigning it to `recipientList` ?

```
var result = $.parseJSON(data);
self.recipientList(result);
```

Comment: it takes 2 seconds now.love you so much:)